How to find all lie groups with given Lie algebra?
I'm trying to solve a problem that my algebra teacher gave me. Describe all connected Lie groups with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n({R})$, and describe all connected real Lie groups with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(C)$. So i trying to think about a adjoint representation, but i dont what to do next, and is it a true way to solve this problem. So the next that i was trying to think its a universal covering of $GL_n(R)$, but this sound very strange, and i suppose we cant to describe them, so how to correctly this task.

Start by working out the case $n=1$. Do you see why the adjoint representation is not really useful for solving this problem and why $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is a wrong group to consider?

@MoisheKohan, yes, because gl_n(R) is not connected manifold, and adjoint representation in case $n=1$ is a trivial. And i suppose it will be more usefull to consider &GL_n(R)^+$, with $detA>0$.

Yes, just make sure you use proper TeX/Mathjax syntax to write math. But did you figure out what is the answer to your question in the case $n=1$? This will be a part of your solution in the general case.

@MoisheKohan in case $n=1$ we got only 2 Lie groups with algebra Lie $\mathfrak{gl}1(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$, Thats is a $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}{>0}^{\times}$, but any way, i got no idea, how its can help me...

maybe I should look at all diagonal, upper-triangular, lower-triangular matrices in $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{R})$,  but anyway i am confused.
